# JSON formatter that attempts to preserve numerical matrices?

Tags: python, json

I frequently use the function `json.dumps` from the Python standard library's JSON module for applications simillar to the following code snipppet:

```
import json

test = {
    "is_dict": True,
    "has_matrix": True,
    "is_json": True,
    "num_items": 49,
    "data_mat": [[1, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 1, 0, 0],
                 [0, 0, 1, 0],
                 [0, 0, 0, 1]]
}

print(json.dumps(test, indent=2))
```

This results in output that looks like this:

```
{
  "is_dict": true,
  "has_matrix": true,
  "is_json": true,
  "num_items": 49,
  "data_mat": [
    [
      1,
      0,
      0,
      0
    ],
    [
      0,
      1,
      0,
      0
    ],
    [
      0,
      0,
      1,
      0
    ],
    [
      0,
      0,
      0,
      1
    ]
  ]
}
```

My opinion is that it would be better if the output was something like the following:

```
{
    "is_dict": True,
    "has_matrix": True,
    "is_json": True,
    "num_items": 49,
    "data_mat": [[1, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 1, 0, 0],
                 [0, 0, 1, 0],
                 [0, 0, 0, 1]]
}
```

Are there any JSON formatters (for any language) that attempt to produce output that is  more like the second case?

Specifically, I'm looking for an implementation that:

- Detects numerical matrices and attempts to format them better
- Has heuristics to avoid lines with only a few characters
- Any features of similar intent as the above

In the Emacs community, such a feature might be  called "DWIM (Do What I Mean) formatting" or "Electric formatting".

Comment: The gist that is linked in the supposed duplicate fails this test case BTW.

Comment: I use JSON specifically because it is more portable. In my case, I need to write something that can be read by JavaScript.

Comment: The duplicate doesn't serve *your specific* case, no. But it showcases how you _can_ customise the serialisation for your particular opinionated preferences.

Comment: I severely doubt that I'm the only one with this problem